# Remove vlc added time and date stamp from snapshot file name

Tags: command-line, vlc

How can i remove the date and time stamp from these two files which is added vlc automatically 
`109tt.mp4-18-23-09-2019-04-29-18h23m09s041.png`
`110rm.mp4-13-41-44-2019-04-26-13h41m44s618.png`

I want to get my old file name 109tt.png  and 110rm.pm

Anybody can help me

Comment: Some clarification, by `get my old file name` do you want to rename it ?

Comment: yes i want to get the old file name

Comment: I get the feeling you want a `rename` command that will do both in the same command, but your question is vague & doesn't specif ally ask for this (ie. waltinator's use of two `mv` commands answers your asked question).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually:

```
mv 109tt.mp4-18-23-09-2019-04-29-18h23m09s041.png 109tt.png
mv 110rm.mp4-13-41-44-2019-04-26-13h41m44s618.png 110rm.pm
```

Comment: i want to do it the commands